# How to create a legend for quantitative visualization with increasing icon size?

Tags: qgis, legend, visualisation, maps, chart

I am trying to find a way to do a map and legend like this:

[image: Quantitative visualization]

I am using QGIS 2.6 Brighton. The only way was to do a pie chart but I think it's not possible to create classes. I can create circles with a categorized style but I couldn't figure out how to create such a legend.